# Apple SearchKit on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

Can I use the Apple SearchKit indexing framework in iOS, or is it only Mac OS?  And can someone point me in the direction of some tutorials for getting that hooked up in iOS?

Thanks

Comment: hi! Did you find any solution on this? I read on the comments that you use LuceneKit. Is there any good docs or tutorias for understanding the whole process. I need to make a search in all app. Is that practicable?? thanks

Comment: I have been using [locayta](http://www.locayta.com/iOS-search-engine/locayta-search-mobile/).  The documentation is pretty solid at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Search Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SearchKitConcepts/searchKit_intro/searchKit_intro.html), Search Kit is only available for OS X, not iOS. So far there is no API for Spotlight in iOS either.

Comment: Is there some sort of equivalent library for document content indexing and searching?  I've got the LuceneKit port working, but it isn't finished and is lacking phrase queries.

Comment: Just found locayta mobile at locayata.com.  The documentation is slightly lacking, but the framework is excellently built.

Comment: Sadly, they want $1,000 for a commercial license...I'm not saying they don't deserve it for a great product, just that I'm not prepared to spend that for my project.